# How to config nextjs typescript to use sass and nextjs fonts

Tags: css, typescript, sass

im trying to config next js typescript app to work with sass and next js font i have following [this artical](https://medium.com/quick-code/next-js-style-with-sass-scss-fonts-54e9cef70377)

without font module styles are working properly

here is my without font next.config.js

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
const withFont = require('nextjs-fonts');

module.exports =withSass({
    cssModules: true
  });
```

this is how i have try to config fonts to app

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withFonts = require('nextjs-fonts');
module.exports = withSass(withFonts({
  webpack(config, options) {
   return config;
  },
}));
```

when i change next.config.js like this app will stop using styles
how can i fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next.js has built-in sass support (including css modules) starting from version `9.3`.
To avoid conflicts, the feature is disabled if you're using `@zeit/next-sass` or css related plugins.

https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#built-in-sass-support-for-global-stylesheets

When `nextjs-fonts` or `next-fonts` is published, there are some issues when importing font files, but not anymore now, surely you don't need nextjs-fonts, you can define the @font-face css in `.scss` file.

[Checkout this related Github issues](https://github.com/rohanray/next-fonts/issues/34)